# Link to specific accordion section from another page

Tags: jquery, accordion

I've added the jquery UI accordion to my site, which is working fine. However I want other pages to link to certain sections within that accordion. So for example I need data-cleansing.php to link to section 3 of the accordion on page data.php

This is the basic js for the jquery accordion

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
  </script>
```

and the html

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget.
    Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in,
    condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros.
    Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio.</p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Sed non urna. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus.
    Vivamus hendrerit, dolor aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis velit,
    faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo.</p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus.
    Quisque lobortis.Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa.</p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've found this from looking through questions posted on here but it isn't working as I'm linking to the section from another page. I've tried adding the url in the relevant "open section" but not linking to that page:

http://jsfiddle.net/VZ3T5/5/

and also [How to link to specific accordion section from different page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044035/how-to-link-to-specific-accordion-section-from-different-page?s=2|1.1931)

so I tried:

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion(option", "active", 0);
```

which broke the accordion.

If anyone could shed any light it'd be much appreciated,

Thank you
Rachael

Comment: Looks like you missed an opening quotation mark at "option": $( "#accordion" ).accordion(option", "active", 0);

Comment: Thanks Trolle. I've just tried that and it made each section open.

Comment: Well, in answer to your actual question, I believe you would do that server side. You could also use localstorage to set a varialble that persists across pageloads. Or do what sebzzz suggests :).

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion("option", "active", [your data panel id here]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sebbzzz - but how do you define which section opens, from which page?

Comment: Try this:
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $accordion = $("#accordion");
    var panelId = location.hash.replace("#", "");
    $accordion.accordion({
        active: panelId
    });
});

and access the page by example.com#2

Comment: For example there's a few sections in the accordion I need to link to, from different pages.

Comment: Thanks again Sebbzzz, I've uploaded the page here http://rachtesting.co.uk/accordion.html I've updated that code but it hasn't made a difference- please would you mind having a look?

Comment: Edit :
"location.hash.replace("#", "");" 
To:
"intParse(location.hash.replace("#", ""));"

and it will work :)

Comment: Thanks again Sebbzzz! I've added that now but getting 'reference error, can't find variable intparse' - is it something to do with the page being .html?

Comment: Oh god, sorry - It's supposed to be parseInt. And make sure to capitalize it like that :)